# Stop Access creating new record with navigation right arrow

Tags: ms-access

I'm working with Access 2007.

In my forms, if a user reaches the last record and accidentally clicks on the right arrow in the navigation bar, Access creates and automatically saves a new blank record. This results in the underlying table getting filled with blank records.

How do I stop this happening, in VBA or otherwise?

I have an Add button on the form to create a new record.

Comment: Remove the inbuilt navigation buttons and make you own, then disable the next record button if they are on the last record, and similarly the previous button if you are on the first record.

Comment: When reaching the new record, it isn't saved automatically. There must be some code that does this, and this code is what needs to be changed.

Comment: So I've now discovered. It's been a few years since I wrote the code and have had to relearn it. I've solved the problem by disabling the record button (temporarily re-enabling it when a user clicks on the Add button).

Answer (score 0):

Browsing to a new record doesn't - on its own - create and save a new record.

So, remove the code you have, that either sets values of one or more fields or saves the record.